# Is it possible to know if the parameter was defaulted

Tags: c++, c++11, default-parameters

**Caution: This problem is limited to MSVS**

I have this function signature:

```
void do_somthing(std::vector<foo>&  bar={});
```

Is it possible to differ between those two calls for the function:

First:

```
do_something()
```

Second:

```
std::vector<foo> v;
do_something(v);
```

In other words, I want something like:

```
void do_somthing(std::vector<foo>&  bar={}){
    if(/* bar was defaulted*/){

    }
    else{

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
The actual code:

```
template<class Tinput_iterator>
            Tmodel perform_fitting(Tinput_iterator begin_data, Tinput_iterator end_data, std::vector<Tpoint>& inliers = {});
```

Comment: How about *two* functions, one with (normal, default-less) parameter, one without?

Comment: @deviantfan sure that is a right solution and it is actually what I am planing to do. But I was curious if it is possible to do it in the same function

Comment: @JamesAdkison, if it was defaulted that mean the output of this parameter is not needed, so i would not compute it in the function and save some performance

Comment: So the parameter is needed when the caller explicitly gives it an empty `vector`? What will it do with the provided empty `vector` that it wouldn't do with the defaulted empty `vector`?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi You could use `if(bar.empty()) return;`

Comment: @HumamHelfawi you mean that `std::vector` is used to store output? Is there a reason for not returning by value?

Comment: Sounds you want a `bool paramIsImportant` as another parameter

Comment: I just noticed, you edited the question and removed the `const` and you are using it as an output parameter ...

Comment: @NathanOliver it is empty in the both cases

Comment: @TartanLlama yup. bad design which I can not change now

Comment: @JamesAdkison yes you notified me by your comment :)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Your code isn't valid C++ anyway. You can't bind a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary.

Comment: Wait a minute this code won't even compile.  You cannot have a lvalue reference to a temporary which is what you default parameter is.  If you change to a `const&` then this question is silly as you just check if the vector is `empty()`.  Even if you pass a vector from the call site if it is empty there is nothing you can do with the vector as it is `const`.

Comment: I am sorry I was editing it from my prginal code and forget to do it well. I edited

Comment: Yeah this question is based upon a false premise.

Comment: This code will still not compile as you are trying to bind a temporary to a lvalue reference.

Comment: @HumamHelfaw The actual code shouldn't compile, are you using MSVC?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Then it's using a non-standard extension, you shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi This is a non standard extension and you should stop using it.  It will make your code non portable.

Comment: @TartanLlama I see! it is totally fair now. I will go for the two functions solution and rest in peace. Thanks for all of you guys :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have this function signature:
>
> ```
> void do_somthing(std::vector<foo>&  bar=std::vector<foo>{});
> ```

This **cannot compile**, except with dangerous non-standard compiler settings you should stay away from.

In particular, Visual C++ allows this if `/Za` is not specified, but with `/W4` still produces a warning like this:

```
stackoverflow.cpp(6): warning C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'default argument': conversion from 'std::vector<foo,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector<foo,
std::allocator<_Ty>> &'
        with
        [
            _Ty=foo
        ]
stackoverflow.cpp(6): note: A non-const reference may only be bound to an lvalue
```

> ```
> void do_somthing(std::vector<foo>&  bar=std::vector<foo>{}){
>     if(/* bar was defaulted*/){
>
>     }
>     else{
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Even if we assume that you actually included the missing `const` to make the code compile, the answer would be: no, it is **not possible** to know if `bar` was defaulted.

Whatever you plan to do here, you have to find a completely different solution.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't realize the parameter was non-`const`.

Answer (score 4):

No, not directly. The default parameter is substituted by the compiler at the call site without any further information.

However, there is a simple solution to achieve what you want to do: Use overloading instead of default parameters.

```
namespace detail
{
  void
  do_something_impl(const std::vector<foo>& foos)
  {
    // Do things that always need to be done…
  }
}

void
do_something()
{
  // Do things specific to the no-argument case…
  detail::do_something_impl({});
}

void
do_something(const std::vector<foo>& foos)
{
  // Do things specific to the one-argument case…
  detail::do_something_impl(foos);
}
```

If your logic requires you to branch more often – not just at the beginning or the end of the function – you could pass an additional boolean parameter to `detail::do_something_impl` that encodes which overload it was called from.

In general, I recommend to use defaulted parameters sparingly and prefer function overloading as it gives you better control and often also better (less surprising) interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

> > Is it possible to differ between those two calls for the function?

No.  You can check if the vector is empty, but otherwise there is no way to distinguish them.

You can do clever things, such as passing a utility class that converts, but that isn't bulletproof and is mostly pointless since you can more easily make two different function overloads.